# Memory performance improvement for downloading images for a large dataset

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am currently making a program that fetches movie/series details from a url and decodes them into a ContentModel, then tries to download the image for each posterURL in the model and then returns it:

```
struct ContentModel: Decodable {
    let url: URL
    let title: String
    let type: String
    let posterUrl: URL
    let description: String
    let aggregateRating: AggregateRating?
    let contentRating: String?
    let genre: [String]
    let trailer: Trailer?
    let actor: [Individual]
    let director: [Individual]
}

func parseContentJSON(_ contentID: String) async throws -> ContentModel {
        
        // hidden code: url setting, calling session, getting response and data
        
        do {
            var content = try jsonDecoder.decode(Short.self, from: data).short
            content.poster = await downloadImage(from: content.posterUrl) //performs affecting line
            return content
        } catch {
            throw ParseError.invalidData
        }
    }
```

when I just call the function and do not try to set the content.poster using downloadImage(from:) the memory performance stays fixed at around 25MB, however when adding that line as above code, and this function is called about 50 times, the memory usage jumps to 800MB (I expect it to increase even more with more function calls) this is not sustainable, is there a way to reduce the memory performance?

I call the function in the context below

```
let contentsID: [String] = [...] // about 50 IDs in it

func loadContentConcurrent(start startIndex: Int, end endIndex: Int) async {
        var all: [ContentModel] = []
        
        try? await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: ContentModel?.self) { group in
            for contentID in contentsID[startIndex..<endIndex] {
                group.addTask {
                    // TODO: creates memory leak; work on this
                    return try? await self.parseContentJSON(contentID)
                }
            }
            
            for try await contentFound in group {
                if let safeContent = contentFound {
                    all.append(safeContent)
                }
            }
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self, all] in
            self?.contents += all
            self?.contentLoadedCount += all.count
        }
        
    }
```

to remove ambiguity, these props and methods are inside a ViewModel and I call the function once inside the initializer and afterwards recurringly call it from inside the View associated with the ViewModel. I am using pagination technique (i.e. call this function in junks of 5 ids every sometime and not all 50 ids in the ContentIDs list.

Comment: How large are the images, could you decrease their seize and/or quality? Perhaps save them locally and only load them into memory when you need them?

Comment: the size images are mostly 1900 × 2814, i am not sure how i can reduce thier quality while fetching. Also, i do not want to save the images locally as the contentIDs will later be dynamically updated with other contents, therefore new contentIDs and that would defeat the point.

Comment: You could still store them temporarily to disk while the app is running. And I meant to reduce size when saving to disk.

Comment: how would that be possible?

Comment: What be possible?

Comment: i do not want to store any data prior to runtime since i want everything to be dynamic. therefore putting them in asset (if thats what u mean) would not be what i desire

Comment: This isn’t really leading anywhere. Why would I be talking about adding them as assets when the whole discussion is about downloading images while the app is running?